# How do I ensure a UTC date created from a string is valid?

Tags: javascript

Users can enter a date in an input. This value is parsed into a UTC date. However, it seems to be parsing invalid dates as dates.

For example:

```
Date.UTC('1990', '1', '1111');
```

returns a valid date object (specifically `Thu Jan 14 1993 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`)

I know if I use `new Date('1/1111/1990')` it would give an invalid date, but how would I do this with UTC dates?

Comment: why do you need to validate UTC date? just validate entered date and then convert it to UTC

Comment: I just need to end up with a valid UTC date. The validation doesn't necessarily have to be on the UTC date itself, I was just hoping there was a way. Currently I am checking by using `new Date(dateStr)` and validating that but it seems like an unnecessary extra step when I just want to end up with UTC date. @Mara

Comment: From my point of view you are mixing up different things. UTC is Coordinated Universal Time is the time standard by which the world regulates clocks and time. If you have string you can validate e.x. with regex if it is UTC format or not. but you can not validate date itself.

Comment: ah interesting. I think you are right that I was mixing things up. thanks for the explanation @Mara